# Flatten pandas data frame with a JSON column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **very large** dataset in CSV format in which one column is a JSON string. I want to read this information into a **flat** Pandas data frame. How can I achieve this efficiently?

Input CSV:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,Programming,"{""col3_1"":null,""col3_2"":""Java""}",11
2,Sport,"{""col3_1"":null,""col3_2"":""Soccer""}",22
3,Food,"{""col3_1"":null,""col3_2"":""Pizza""}",33
```

Expected DataFrame:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   col1    |    col2     |   col3_1    |   col3_2  |   col4    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1      | Programming |    None     |    Java   |    11     |
|    2      |    Sport    |    None     |   Soccer  |    22     |
|    3      |    Food     |    None     |   Pizza   |    33     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can currently get the expected output using the following code. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same.

```
import json
import pandas
dataset = pandas.read_csv('/dataset.csv')
dataset['col3'] = dataset['col3'].apply(json.loads)
dataset['col3_1'] = dataset['col3'].apply(lambda row: row['col3_1'])
dataset['col3_2'] = dataset['col3'].apply(lambda row: row['col3_2'])
dataset = dataset.drop(columns=['col3'])
```

Answer (score 6):

you can parse JSON in Pandas column using `json.loads()` and convert it to Pandas columns using `pd.Series()`:

```
In [85]: df.join(df.pop('col3').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x))))
Out[85]:
   col1         col2  col4 col3_1  col3_2
0     1  Programming    11   None    Java
1     2        Sport    22   None  Soccer
2     3         Food    33   None   Pizza
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `pd.Series` is completely inefficient in my case. The execution time increased by a factor of about 25 compared to the implementation provided in the question (0.27 to 7.19 seconds for a dataset with 30000 rows).

Answer (score 4):

Use for better performance `DataFrame` contructor with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col3').apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist(), index=df.index)
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   col1         col2  col4 col3_1  col3_2
0     1  Programming    11   None    Java
1     2        Sport    22   None  Soccer
2     3         Food    33   None   Pizza
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.pop('col3').apply(pd.io.json.loads))
0      {'col3_1': None, 'col3_2': 'Java'}
1    {'col3_1': None, 'col3_2': 'Soccer'}
2     {'col3_1': None, 'col3_2': 'Pizza'}
Name: col3, dtype: object

print (pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col3').apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist(), index=df.index))
  col3_1  col3_2
0   None    Java
1   None  Soccer
2   None   Pizza
```

Solutions are similar, but performance is different:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [204]: %timeit df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['col3'].apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist(), index=df.index))
10 loops, best of 3: 76.4 ms per loop

In [205]: %timeit df.join(df['col3'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x))))
1 loop, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop
```

Comment: `pd.io.json.loads` performed much better than `json.loads`. Thank you for this hint.
Using `pd.io.json.loads` in both implementations the implementation provided in the question performed slightly better than this one.

Comment: @JoePhi - ya, your question is really data dependent issue, is possible see your json sample data?

Comment: @jezrael: yes, see my 'answer' below... 
Column 'efforts' is the one with json strings. They are rather simple: list of tuples, with <string>:<float value>